# c# parse javascript content

Tags: c#, javascript, parsing

So I have a web scraping project where one of the pages has all the necessary content in JSON format inside a set of `<script>` tags.

here's an example of said `<script>` tags:

```
<script>
  window.postData = {}
  window.postData["content"] = [json content]
</script>
```

I've used the HtmlAgilityPack to get to the particular `<script>` tags, but I am not sure how to grab just the json content from this.  I can parse the JSON with JSON.net or other library/framework, so I'm not worried about that part.  I'm just stuck on getting just the Json.  Is there a javascript parsing library or something that I can use to get this, or is there another way to accomplish this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint)

```
var postDataJSON = new Engine()
    .Execute("window.postData = {}; window.postData['content'] = [json content]")
    .GetValue("window.postData");
```

Comment: My guess is that this would crash since `window` will be undefined. Prepending `window = {};` to the string should solve that though. Jint is a cool project but it's only a js-interpreter, it won't get far with scripts written for a browser that relies on the `window`-object or the DOM. Personally I would probably have solved this with a regex instead.

Comment: @kavun is this expecting me to know what the `[json content]` is supposed to be?  what if I don't know what the content is? and only know that there is content there?

I guess I could just dump the HtmlNode text content for the `<script>` node as `string nodeText = node.InnerText;` and use it as `.Execute(nodeText).GetValue("window.postData");` ???

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren I'm not opposed to using regex, but I'm not that good with it.

Comment: @kavun Thank you very much.  I'm going to give that a try and see how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: @kavun if I had a script that had: `window.postData["content"] = [json content]       window.postData["content-2"] = [json content]` could I look at only one of the items or would I be stuck with looking at the two combined together?  or would I be needing to post another question for that?

Comment: @kavun I actually receive an unhandle `Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException` with no message content when using this.

Comment: @shadonar there are other options you could try: (1) http://jurassic.codeplex.com/, (2) http://dlr.codeplex.com/ + http://myjscript.codeplex.com/, and/or (3) http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/